# A button to start in highcharts

Tags: button, dynamic, highcharts

Here is my charts, dynamically update. Now im trying to add a button which, to start the dynamic charts.

Ideally, i wish the data to be initialized when i press the button, however it seems that the data could not be initialized simultaneously with the method.Or let's be simply, is it possible to add a button that i could control, when to start the chart and, when to stop or pause?

```
var time = null;
var bol = false;
var chart;
var data = [];
// function play(){
// var time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;
// for(i = -1999; i <= 0; i += 1){
//     data.push([
//         time + i *1000,
//         Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
//         ]);
// }
// }

data = (function () {
    var data = [], time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;
    for (i = -1999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
        data.push([time + i * 1000, Math.round(Math.random() * 100)]);
    }
    return data;
}());
```

Comment: Is this example showing what you would like to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/nob6x98y/

Comment: yes. As you may see that, series needs the data, so i moved the data to the global scope

Comment: So you would like to get something similar to this example? http://jsfiddle.net/nob6x98y/1/